# How can I rename the image dynamically before uploading it in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new in php and trying to build a registration system in which every user must upload his or her image. I want to save the image with the name as users ID so that no images can have same name but I don't know how to do it. Please Help..!!

**Here is the code**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
Choose a file to upload: 
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>


<?php $target_path = "uploads/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
 header("Location: contactinfo.php");
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

Try doing this:

```
$target_path = $target_path . $userid . '.jpg';
```

The data after `$target_path` determines what the file name is going to be.

Trusting the extension (.gif, .jpg, .png) that the user's browser provides isn't always safe. Nor is trusting `$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["type"]`.
If you also allow users to upload SVG, GIF, PNG, or other image types, you can guess the correct extension based on the content-type of the file, determined through [Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php) or [GD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php).

Answer (score 0):

In your

```
target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
```

This will be the name including path for the new file, so if you want to rename it just type

```
filename=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
$extension=end(explode(".", $filename));
$newfilename="file_". $userid .".".$extension;
```

Answer (score 0):

by exemple:

$target_path = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path);

To save it with an unique id you can use strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) in the name of your new picture.

If have more questions you can add me http://www.newvibe.ca/ludovic.ledoux

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you allow user to upload same filename *multiple* times and not overwrite the old file, insert a random text into the filename using `uniqid();`

`$target_path = $target_path . uniqid($user_id) . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);`

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php